# Codename One - Mask and Unmask Password Field on iOS

Tags: java, codenameone

```
TextField password = new TextField("", "Pass Word", 15, TextField.PASSWORD);
CheckBox maskAndUnmaskCheck = new CheckBox();
maskAndUnmaskCheck.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if(maskAndUnmaskCheck.isSelected()) {
           password.setConstraint(TextField.ANY); 
        } else{
            password.setConstraint(TextField.PASSWORD);
        }
    }
});
```

We are using the above code to display the password without mask i.e showing the text that what he types when a user selects the check box.

The above code is working perfectly with Android mobiles, the code is not working on iPhone devices.

Is there any way to achieve the same in on iPhone too.

Do I need any code changes for iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I noticed that is missing there is: `repaint()` or `revalidate()`.

```
final TextField password = new TextField("","Pass Word",15,TextField.PASSWORD);
CheckBox maskAndUnmaskCheck = new CheckBox();
maskAndUnmaskCheck.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if(maskAndUnmaskCheck.isSelected()){
           password.setConstraint(TextField.ANY); 
        } else {
            password.setConstraint(TextField.PASSWORD);
        }
        if(password.isEditing()) {
            password.stopEditing();
            password.startEditingAsync();
        } else {
            password.getParent().revalidate(); 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Diamond. It's working but observed one thing, when we have a cursor with a keyboard on TextField unmasking is not working. Once done on the keyboard its working fine. Do we need to consider any attribute to do this?.

Comment: The keyboard is supposed to close when you tap the checkbox because the TexField should have lost its focus by then and the masking/unmasking should work.

Comment: Added a couple of lines to @Diamond's answer that handle the case of doing this while editing