# Add an icon inside a Codename One TextModeLayout

Tags: codenameone

My problem is that I didn't find any way to properly add an icon near a `TextComponent`, inside a `TextModeLayout`, to mask/unmask a password.

**It's a layout problem only**, because the code of the `ActionListener` to mask/unmask the password works correctly at least in the Simulator (it's taken from [Codename One - Mask and Unmask Password Field on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42807405/codename-one-mask-and-unmask-password-field-on-ios)).

On iPhone skin, the `InputComponents` labels and text fields are not aligned correctly:
[image]

On Android skin, the text is not aligned correctly if it doesn't valide:
[image]

About my code, instead of adding the `InputComponent` (of the password) directly to the `TextModeLayout` container, I enclosed the `InputComponent` and the `Button` inside a `BorderLayout`, and then I added the `BorderLayout` container to the `TextModeLayout` container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do that the text mode layout stops working for that component as it's unaware of the layout in the hierarchy. The hierarchy in the border layout is the responsibility of that layout.

The solution is to extend the `TextComponent` and add that functionality to Codename One. As a workaround we might be able to rely on the behavior of the current component since the field is already in a border layout component. So something like this might work:

```
TextField tf = myTextComponent.getField();
Container b = tf.getParent();
b.add(EAST, unmask);
```

Comment: For the readers: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2654